# Can I test push notifications received for my app under test using Xamarin Test Recorder?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I've a trial version of Xamarin Test Recorder currently installed on my machine. I am trying to test if my app (android app) receives push notifications in particular scenarios. Also, the Xamarin test recorder was not able to record the event when I tapped on a push notification and got navigated to my app.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, system dialogs are outside the scope of Xamarin UITests so you won't be able to see them in the tree when using a tool like REPL (read-eval-print-loop) or when recording tests with the Xamarin Test Recorder.

However, you could take a look at [Appium](http://appium.io/). It can be used to read notifications and it's been supported in Xamarin Test Cloud since the beginning of this year.

Another possibility would be to use Google's [UI Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html) that can also read notifications. I'm not sure how it would work with a Xamarin application though.